# Connect JPA(Hibernate) with Websockets - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, websocket

I've got new project to do and it's web chat application with websockets and every sended message should save in MySQL db.

So, I've made chat app through some tutorial and all code looks like this.

*ChatController.java*

```
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider;
import javax.websocket.*;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@ServerEndpoint("/ws")
public class ChatServer {
private Map<String, String> usernames = new HashMap<String, String>();


//----Here is my problem
public PersistenceProvider persistenceProvider = new HibernatePersistenceProvider();
private EntityManager entityManager = persistenceProvider.
        createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit", new HashMap()).createEntityManager();
//----Up there
@OnOpen
public void open(Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException {
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText("(Server): Welcome to the chat room. Please state your username to begin.");

}

@OnClose
public void close(Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException {
    String userId = session.getId();
    if (usernames.containsKey(userId)) {
        String username = usernames.get(userId);
        usernames.remove(userId);
        for (Session peer : session.getOpenSessions())
            peer.getBasicRemote().sendText("(Server): " + username + " left the chat room.");
    }
}

@OnMessage
public void handleMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException {
    String userId = session.getId();
    if (usernames.containsKey(userId)) {
        String username = usernames.get(userId);
        //dbConn.addMessage(username,message);
        for (Session peer : session.getOpenSessions()) {
            peer.getBasicRemote().sendText("(" + username + "): " + message);
        }
    } else {
        if (usernames.containsValue(message) || message.toLowerCase().equals("server"))
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("(Server): That username is already in use. Please try again.");
        else {
            usernames.put(userId, message);
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("(Server): Welcome, " + message + "!");
            for (Session peer : session.getOpenSessions())
                if (!peer.getId().equals(userId))
                    peer.getBasicRemote().sendText("(Server): " + message + " joined the chat room.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Chat</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;">
<textarea title="Chat Log" id="log" readonly
      style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 600px; resize: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;"></textarea>
<input title="Chat Input" id="input" type="text" style="display: block; width: 100%; border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;"
   autofocus/>
<script>
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/LastChat_war_exploded/ws");
    ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log(event.data);
    document.getElementById("log").value += "[" + timestamp() + "] " + event.data + "\n";
    }

    document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            ws.send(event.target.value);
            event.target.value = "";
        }
    });

    function timestamp() {
        var d = new Date(), minutes = d.getMinutes();
        if (minutes < 10) minutes = '0' + minutes;
        return d.getHours() + ':' + minutes;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*persistance.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.entities.MessagesEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

So Websocket chat is working, but when I'm trying to add that two lines in ChatController I've end up with *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/jpa/HibernatePersistenceProvider* error

In my previous app where I need only to connect with MySQL thorugh JPA this lines works like a charm.
I've got everything like before.
Libraries:
JPA 2.1
Hibernate-entitymanager:5.2.10
mysql-connector-java-5.1.43

Also I'm using Intellij IDEA 2017.2.1

I've been searching for long time and finally give up.
Please help me with that error, but if you got information what should I use to make that project work, maybe some other languages or some frameworks - don't be afraid to tell :)

EDIT:
*Full*

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/jpa/HibernatePersistenceProvider
at com.euro24.chat.ChatServer.<init>(ChatServer.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ReflectionHelper.getInstance(ReflectionHelper.java:865)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.DefaultComponentProvider.create(DefaultComponentProvider.java:60)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ComponentProviderService.getInstance(ComponentProviderService.java:239)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ComponentProviderService.getEndpointInstance(ComponentProviderService.java:300)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.server.TyrusServerEndpointConfigurator.getEndpointInstance(TyrusServerEndpointConfigurator.java:182)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint$1.getEndpointInstance(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:149)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ComponentProviderService.getInstance(ComponentProviderService.java:151)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint.callMethod(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:494)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint.onOpen(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:570)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusEndpointWrapper.onConnect(TyrusEndpointWrapper.java:766)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocket.onConnect(TyrusWebSocket.java:155)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocketEngine$TyrusConnection.<init>(TyrusWebSocketEngine.java:821)
```

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError : either the class in question or one of its dependencies is not in the CLASSPATH. Basic java

Comment: Eeem, Neil could You explain what should I do because I don't really get it. What You mean "is not in the CLASSPATH"?

Answer (score 0):

As Neil points out, you don't have the class in your class path.
Check the module settings in IntelliJ and look if it's in the libraries folder if you use that, or use add it as a source in project settings as pointed out here:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206863325-Howto-add-a-directory-to-the-classpath-

In general just read up on what the CLASSPATH means for example here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html